# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-'

Tags: php, html, php7

lo que pasa es que ya tengo mi conexión a la base de datos hecha pero cuando quiero mostrar ese dato.

Me aparece este error:

> ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\wamp64\www\proyectos\noticias\articulos.php on line 18

Adjunto mi código gracias:

```
    <?php require_once "./includes/head.php"; ?>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/articulos.css">
    
    <?php require_once "./includes/header.php" ?>
    
    <section class="notices">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="info">
                <h2>Ultimas Noticias</h2>
                <h3>Conozca las ultimas noticias de nuestro colegio</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="grid">
                <?php
                    $query = mysqli_query($database, "SELECT titulo, descripcion, fecha, imagen FROM articulos");
                    $result = mysqli_query($database, $query);
                    while ($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        echo "<div> $mostrar['titulo'] </div>";
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

<?php require_once "./includes/footer.php" ?>
```

En el editor se queda marcado en rojo la primera comilla simple de `$mostrar['titulo'];`.

> **PD:** El include head contiene la **`conexion.php`** de la base de datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando vas a mostrar codigo dinámico intercalado con código estático, como en este caso lo es de PHP con el de HTML debes dejarlo así:

```
echo "<div>".$mostrar['titulo']."</div>";
```

De modo que concatenas envueltos entre comillas las tags de HTML con la variable creada en PHP.

De lo contrario el símbolo de cierre `>` del lado de HTML genera conflicto en PHP.

Comment: si me funciono, muchas gracias, me equivoque en la cosa mas simple.